# How does the number of object detection classes affect performance in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I'm using TensorFlow's object detection API. I trained my custom model from SSD_MOBILENET_COCO_2 that originally had 90 detection classes. My custom model only has 1 detection class and performance seems to be similar. Is there any relationship between the number of classes and the performance of the model? Why?

Answer (score 0):

No, There is no relationship between number of classes and performance of the model. Performance of the model depends upon the hyper parameters.